# How to loop through two lists and work on the match?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have two lists. I want to be able to iterate using for loops, and want to do some operation on the element based on matched element. I cannot figure out what going wrong here,

```
lst1 = ["a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "g1"] 
lst2 = ["c1", "d1", "e1"]

for l in lst1:
    for m in lst2:
        if l == m:
            v = l + "__match_found"
        else:
            v = l + "__no_match"
    print(v)
```

I am getting following output:

```
a1__no_match
b1__no_match
c1__no_match
d1__no_match
e1__match_found
f1__no_match
g1__no_match
```

I am expecting that each element should only be printed once, either with match, or no_match the end.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Take a look at the for..else loop in Python. You can execute a break statement when you find a match. If no match(break) encountered, the else clause executes to print no match.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, when `l` is `c1`, in each iteration of your inner loop:

- `m` is `c1`: `v = l + "__match_found"`
- `m` is `d1`: `v = l + "__no_match"`
- `m` is `e1`: `v = l + "__no_match"`

You then print only the final value of v.

Instead, when you find a match, you should be using `break` to dis-continue the inner loop:

```
for l in lst1:
    for m in lst2:
        if l == m:
            v = l + "__match_found"
            break
        else:
            v = l + "__no_match"        
    print(v)
```

A cleaner way to do this would be using `in`:

```
for l in lst1:
    if l in lst2:
        print (l + "__match_found")
    else:
        print (l + "__no_match")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you print `v` in the outer loop, you will get whatever the last value of `m` assigned to it. This is not what you want: you want to `break` out of the inner loop as soon as you find a match:

```
for l in lst1:
    v = l + "__no_match"
    for m in lst2:
        if l == m:
            v = l + "__match_found"
            break
    print(v)
```

Now let's simplify the and make it more pythonic. First, the inner loop is just a check for containment. In python, that's usually done with the `in` operator:

```
for l in lst1:
    v = "__match_found" if l in lst2 else "__no_match"
    print(l + v)
```

Now if your only goal is to check for containment, you are much better off using `set` than `list` as your container. For example:

```
s1 = set(lst1)
s2 = set(lst2)

for i in s1 & s2:
    print(i + '__match_found')
for i in s1 - s2:
    print(i + '__no_match')
```

These operations are done with hashables, and are much faster than the linear lookup of lists.